# Using XPath in Python with LXML

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, contains

I have a python script used to parse XMLs and export into a csv file certain elements of interest. I have tried to now change the script to allow the filtering of an XML file under a criteria, the equivalent XPath query would be:

```
\DC\Events\Confirmation[contains(TransactionId,"GTEREVIEW")]
```

When I try to use lxml to do so, my code is:

```
xml_file = lxml.etree.parse(xml_file_path)
namespace = "{" + xml_file.getroot().nsmap[None] + "}"
node_list = xml_file.findall(namespace + "Events/" + namespace + "Confirmation[TransactionId='*GTEREVIEW*']")
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?
Example of XML file:

```
<Events>
  <Confirmation>
    <TransactionId>GTEREVIEW2012</TransactionId>
  </Confirmation>    
  <Confirmation>
    <TransactionId>GTEDEF2012</TransactionId>
  </Confirmation>    
</Events>
```

So I want all "Confirmation" nodes that contain a transaction Id which includes the string "GTEREVIEW".
Thanks

Comment: where is your xml file ?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`findall()` doesn't support XPath expressions, only *ElementPath* (see https://web.archive.org/web/20200504162744/http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm). ElementPath doesn't support searching for elements containing a certain string.

Why don't you use XPath? Assuming that the file `test.xml` contains your sample XML, the following works:

```
> python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree=etree.parse("test.xml")
>>> tree.xpath("Confirmation[starts-with(TransactionId, 'GTEREVIEW')]")
[<Element Confirmation at 0x7f68b16c3c20>]
```

If you insist on using `findall()`, the best you can do is get the list of all `Confirmation` elements having a `TransactionId` child node:

```
>>> tree.findall("Confirmation[TransactionId]")
[<Element Confirmation at 0x7f68b16c3c20>, <Element Confirmation at 0x7f68b16c3ea8>]
```

You then need to filter this list manually, e.g.:

```
>>> [e for e in tree.findall("Confirmation[TransactionId]")
     if e[0].text.startswith('GTEREVIEW')]
[<Element Confirmation at 0x7f68b16c3c20>]
```

If your document contains namespaces, the following will get you all `Confirmation` elements having a `TransactionId` child node, provided that the elements use the default namespace (I used `xmlns="file:xyz"` as the default namespace):

```
>>> tree.findall("//{{{0}}}Confirmation[{{{0}}}TransactionId]".format(tree.getroot().nsmap[None]))
[<Element {file:xyz}Confirmation at 0x7f534a85d1b8>, <Element {file:xyz}Confirmation at 0x7f534a85d128>]
```

And there is of course `etree.ETXPath`:

```
>>> find=etree.ETXPath("//{{{0}}}Confirmation[starts-with({{{0}}}TransactionId, 'GTEREVIEW')]".format(tree.getroot().nsmap[None]))
>>> find(tree)
[<Element {file:xyz}Confirmation at 0x7f534a85d1b8>]
```

This allows you to combine XPath and namespaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Sadly, there is a namespace involved in my doc which results in the Xpath returning an empty list. After removing the namespace from the file, the code appears to work. Is there a way around this? The file essentially begins with 
<DC xmlns="http://tradefinder.db.com/Schemas/MEL/CapitaHorizon_0_9_2.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
And ends with </DC>

Comment: Thought so. You can still use the second approach with `findall()` then. You just need to do the filtering on the node list returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Confirmation[TransactionId[contains(.,'GTEREVIEW')]]


father_tag[child_tag]  # select father_tag that has child_tag
[child_tag[filter]]    # select select child tag which match filter
[filter]
```