# Parsing an ONIX xml with conditions using Python lxml

Tags: python, lxml, onix

I am trying to extract some information from an [*ONIX* XML format](https://www.editeur.org/83/Overview/) file using Python `lxml` parser.

Among other things, the part I am interested in in the document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductSupply>
       <SupplyDetail>
          <Supplier>
             <SupplierRole>03</SupplierRole>
             <SupplierName>EGEN</SupplierName>
          </Supplier>
          <ProductAvailability>40</ProductAvailability>
          <Price>
             <PriceType>01</PriceType>
             <PriceAmount>0.00</PriceAmount>
             <Tax>
                <TaxType>01</TaxType>
                <TaxRateCode>Z</TaxRateCode>
                <TaxRatePercent>0</TaxRatePercent>
                <TaxableAmount>0.00</TaxableAmount>
                <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
             </Tax>
             <CurrencyCode>NOK</CurrencyCode>
          </Price>
          <Price>
             <PriceType>02</PriceType>
             <PriceQualifier>05</PriceQualifier>
             <PriceAmount>0.00</PriceAmount>
             <Tax>
                <TaxType>01</TaxType>
                <TaxRateCode>Z</TaxRateCode>
                <TaxRatePercent>0</TaxRatePercent>
                <TaxableAmount>0.00</TaxableAmount>
                <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
             </Tax>
             <CurrencyCode>NOK</CurrencyCode>
          </Price>
       </SupplyDetail>
    </ProductSupply>
```

I need to pick up the *price amount* with the following conditions:

`PriceType='02' and CurrencyCode='NOK' and PriceQualifier='05'`

I tried:

```
price = p.find(
"ProductSupply/SupplyDetail[Supplier/SupplierRole='03']/Price[PriceType='02' \
and CurrencyCode='NOK' and PriceQualifier='05']/PriceAmount").text
```

For some reason my XPath with `and` operators does not work and get the following error:

```
File "<string>", line unknown
    SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

Any idea how to approach it?
Any assistance is highly appreciated!

Comment: Try using `.xpath()` instead of `.find()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Use `xpath()` because boolean operators like `and` are not supported by `find*()` methods.

---

As [Daniel suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398822/parsing-an-onix-xml-with-conditions-using-python-lxml#comment124445843_70398822), you should use *lxml*'s parser method `xpath()` for your (rather complex) XPath expression.

### XPath

Your XPath expression contains *node tests* and [*predicates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Predicates) which use the [boolean operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Functions_and_operators) [`and` (XPath 1.0)](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-AndExpr):

```
ProductSupply/SupplyDetail[Supplier/SupplierRole='03']/Price[PriceType='02' \
and CurrencyCode='NOK' and PriceQualifier='05']/PriceAmount
```

Tip: Test it online (see [Xpather demo](http://xpather.com/alL7PGZS)). This asserts that it finds a single element `<PriceAmount>0.00</PriceAmount>` as expected.

### Using `find()` methods

According to Python docs you can use following *find* methods which accept a match expression (e.g. XPath) as argument:

1. [`find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find)
2. [`findAll`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall)

### Issue: limited XPath syntax support for `find()`

Although their [supported XPath syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) is limited!

This **limitation includes logical operators** like your `and`. Karl Thornton explains this on his page [XML parsing: Python ~ XPath ~ logical AND | Shiori](https://kaijento.github.io/2017/04/21/xml-parsing-python-xpath-logical-and/#and).

On the other side a [note on *lxml* documentation](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) prefers them:

> The **`.find*()` methods are usually faster** than the full-blown XPath support. They also support incremental tree processing through the .iterfind() method, whereas XPath always collects all results before returning them. They are therefore recommended over XPath for both speed and memory reasons, whenever there is no need for highly selective XPath queries.

(emphasis mine)

#### Using lxml's `xpath()`

So lets start with the safer and richer `xpath()` function (before premature optimization). For example:

```py
# the node predicates to apply within XPath
sd_predicate = "[Supplier/SupplierRole='03']"
p_predicate = "[PriceType='02' and CurrencyCode='NOK' and PriceQualifier='05']"

pa_xpath = f"ProductSupply/SupplyDetail{sd_predicate}/Price{p_predicate}/PriceAmount"  # building XPath including predicates with f-string
print("Using XPath:", pa_xpath) # remove after debugging

root = tree.getroot()
price_amount = root.xpath(pa_xpath)
print("XPath evaluated to:", price_amount) # remove after debugging
```

See also:

- official lxml guide: [XPath and XSLT with lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html)
- [Using XPath in Python with LXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618625/using-xpath-in-python-with-lxml)

Comment: Wow, thank you for a detailed answer!